# MVC Gets NULL Path of the Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to upload images into my App_Data folder.I've used HttpPostedFileBase, but it always returned null for some reason.
Here is my Create method:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult mkCreate(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        return View();

    }
```

Here is my view (Create.cshtml):

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("mkCreate", "Resim", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype= "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Image:</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="Images" id="Images" multiple /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Could you please help me upload images into my App_Data folder?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Image model could be something like this:

```
public class Image
{
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller should have an action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Image image)
{
    foreach (var file in image.Images)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }
    ViewBag.Message = "Image(s) uploaded successfully";
    return View();
 }
```

And finally your view could be something like this:

```
@model AppName.Models.Image

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Image Upload Test</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype "multipart/form-data" }))
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Image:</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="Images" id="Images" multiple /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Comment: This is what I got after trying that : "The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present"

Comment: oh, as you used validateantiforgery token on your controller action, you have to use @Html.AntiForgeryToken() on your form too. check the edited code again please.

Answer (score 0):

TRY WITH THIS  add enctype

```
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
//Rest of the code
}
```

View

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("YourMethod", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
           <input type="file" name="file" id="Images" multiple />
        }
```

Comment: just include `enctype` in `Html.BeginForm()`

Comment: Still getting null :(

Comment: can you update your code..so that we can see what you have done

Comment: OK @Nilesh I did it up there

Comment: got it...just change `input type file` name to `file`

Comment: `<input type="file" name="file" id="Images" multiple />`

Comment: I'm sorry to say I got this "The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present." again

Comment: Add this in your view  `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`